# ML. How to correctly work with sequences

Tags: sml, ml, sequences

So I have this "new" two way sequence:

```
datatype direction = Back | Forward; 
datatype 'a bseq =   bNil 
                | bCons of 'a * (direction -> 'a bseq);
```

and I need a function seq2bseq : 'a seq -> 'a seq -> 'a bseq that "appends" two regular sequences into one like so:

if seqUp is 0 1 2 3 4 ... and seqDown is -1 -2 -3 -4 ... then seq2bseq will create .. -4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 .. . In other words the starter element is the first of seqUp(0) so if I move Back I will get to the first element of seqDown(-1) and two the second of the seqUp(1) if I move Forward. 
So far I wrote the following:

```
fun appendq (Nil, yq) = yq
        | appendq (Cons(x,xf), yq) = Cons(x,fn()=>appendq(xf(),yq));
fun seq2bseq (DownSeq) (UpSeq) =    
        bCons(head(UpSeq), fn (Forward) => seq2bseq appendq(head(UpSeq), DownSeq) tail(UpSeq) 
                            | (Back) => seq2bseq tail(DownSeq) appendq(head(DownSeq), UpSeq) );
```

for which I get the following errors:

```
stdIn:28.101-28.153 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: 'Z seq * 'Z seq -> 'Z seq
  operand:         'Y seq -> 'Y seq
  in expression:
    seq2bseq tail
stdIn:27.5-28.155 Error: right-hand-side of clause doesn't agree with function result type [tycon mismatch]
  expression:  _ seq -> _ bseq
  result type:  _ * _ -> ('Z seq -> 'Z seq) -> _ seq -> _
  in declaration:
    seq2bseq = (fn arg => (fn <pat> => <exp>))
```

I can't figure out what's wrong(:/). Help!
Thanks!

Edit: working(?) code at: http://www.beetxt.com/mkX/.

Comment: i know this is old, but how have you figured it out at last?

Comment: I'm  not sure how correct this code is but I attached what I've managed to found in  the "trash".

Answer (score 2):

Your type errors appear to be coming from a lack of parenthesization.

If you have functions `foo` and `bar`, and want to call `foo` on the result of calling `bar` on the value `baz`, then you need to write this as `foo (bar baz)` or `foo (bar (baz))`, if you prefer.

Writing `foo bar(baz)` will cause `foo` to be called with the argument `bar`, which will likely not type-check.

Try:

```
fun seq2bseq (DownSeq) (UpSeq) =    
    bCons(head(UpSeq),
          fn Forward => seq2bseq (appendq(head(UpSeq), DownSeq)) (tail(UpSeq)) 
           | Back => seq2bseq (tail(DownSeq)) (appendq(head(DownSeq), UpSeq))
         )
```

Comment: Nope :(
this time I get: stdIn:30.48-30.77 Error: operator and operand don't agree [circularity]
  operator domain: 'Z seq * 'Z seq
  operand:         'Z seq * 'Z seq seq seq
  in expression:
    appendq (head DownSeq,UpSeq)

Comment: is there a way to add an element to sequence?

Comment: I can't tell what's going wrong here without knowing what `head` and `tail` are doing. It would appear that your `head` function is of type `'Z seq -> 'Z`, and since your `appendq` expects two `'Z seq`s, you won't be able to append the result of `head` with anything else. This is just a guess, though.  I'm not sure what you mean by add an element to sequence, so I can't really answer that one.