# How can I convert a regular sequence to a biseq in SML?

Tags: sequence, sml

I have the following data type of a 2 way sequence:

```
datatype direction = Back | Forward; 
datatype 'a biseq =   bNil 
                    | bCons of 'a * (direction -> 'a biseq);
```

and I am trying to implement a function that takes a regular sequence:

```
datatype 'a seq = Nil | Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a seq);
```

and converts it to a biseq. so far this is what I wrote:

```
fun new Nil = bNil
  | new (Cons (x, xf)) =
    bCons (x, fn direction => new (xf ()));
```

and it does not work. I assume it is because xf() returns the next seq.
I can't seem to get the previous seq.

Comment: Potentially useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944638/ml-how-to-correctly-work-with-sequences

Comment: yes, I've seen it. it is quite different so it's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: How would you expect to get the previous element? the `seq` data type doesn't encode that information anywhere.

Comment: I need to save all the previous calculated elements in the biseq. I just don’t know how.

Comment: A "history" list? Kind of sounds like a "zipper" data structure with the forward being direction being lazy.